# NaCl GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, google-nativeclient

I am porting a game engine that works perfectly on different platforms (Windows, iOS, Playbook, BB10, Android) to NaCl

2d renders correctly but some 3d Objects don't show or are rendered really strange and i get the following con

```
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION : BackTexture::AllocateStorage: <- error from previous GL command (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: stride not valid for type (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: offset not valid for type (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0 (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: stride not valid for type (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: offset not valid for type (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: stride not valid for type (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: offset not valid for type (index):1
[.PPAPIContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glVertexAttribPointer: stride not valid for type
```

And it repeats indefinitely.

Again, the same render code is used for different platforms and it works just fine. Is there a special consideration to be taken into account when porting to NaCl? Any ideas about what i should focus on to try find the issue?
As far as i can understand, there's a problem with the shader 0 (the vertex shader) and indeed the vertices of some objects are all over the place.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You might be running into a situation where your platform's intrinsic data types differ in size from the GL typedefs. `GLushort` is guaranteed to **always** be 16-bit for instance, while `unsigned short` in C is not. It would help if you listed the code you are using for your calls to `glVertexAttribPointer (...)`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons, Chrome validates many GL operations that other drivers may not. It's a bit of work, but you might try searching the Chromium codebase using http://cs.chromium.org to find the error messages.

Here's what I found:

- [BackTexture::AllocateStorage: <- error from previous GL command](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/command_buffer/service/gles2_cmd_decoder.cc&l=1877)

  This one is tricky to follow. As it says, some previous GL command failed *before* `BackTexture::AllocateStorage` was called. I looked through the rest of the file, and it's not clear to me what command is failing here, but from the error value it is framebuffer related.
- [glVertexAttribPointer: stride not valid for type](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/command_buffer/service/gles2_cmd_decoder.cc&l=6878) and [glVertexAttribPointer: offset not valid for type](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/command_buffer/service/gles2_cmd_decoder.cc&l=6872)

  These are pretty clear -- the stride and offset values are not divisible by the component size. It would be useful to see your calls to `glVertexAttribPointer`.
- [glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/command_buffer/service/vertex_attrib_manager.cc&l=194)

  [`VertexAttrib::CanAccess`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/command_buffer/service/vertex_attrib_manager.cc&rcl=1383365590&l=70) is failing, which checks whether the attrib is enabled, not deleted, and if the vertex index that you're trying to access is valid. As the error says, you are likely referencing a vertex outside of the valid range.

To debug this, I'd narrow down the calls to `glDrawElements` and `glVertexAttribPointer` and try to find which one is failing, then I'd add some `printf` calls to see what values are being passed.

Good luck!